# CSS print background with margin

Tags: css, printing

I am trying to make a print-friendly resume. Everything is working, except for an issue regarding the background image.

I do not want to have any margin on the print page, since otherwise the background image looks messed up:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h2zttd8u6r6hq0g/Screenshot%202015-01-08%2014.38.14.png?dl=0

However, if I do not use any margins, the background looks good but I am unable to do any margin on the second (or other pages):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/16vgu3nahfgeipr/Screenshot%202015-01-08%2014.38.55.png?dl=0

```
body {
    margin: 30px 0;
}
```

That works for the first page, but unfortunately this does not work for any page breaks. Is there a way to do padding/margin in relation to the top/bottom of a print page?

Edit: sorry for the hideous example, but this is basically the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/yugv84qw/

If you press print and save to pdf (in Chrome at least), you'll see that the background fills the entire page. However, when you include

```
@page {
    margin: 1cm 0;
}
```

You will see that the margin I want works, but then the background also uses that margin. In other words: I want the background to stay page filling, while there is a top and bottom margin for text on every page.

Comment: I already am, but that does not make a difference. How would you suggest to implement it then?

Comment: It's impossible to advise if all you've given is a single css property. Please provide a *complete, workable, minimal example* and I (along with anyone else) may be able to advise you better.

Comment: Sorry about that, should have added more info. See the edit.

Comment: [Had the same kind problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130669/page-margin-and-background-image) and solved it with a JS-based solution. Note: my question is about an HTML document designed for printing devices first, but anyway, may your or anyone else's problem be fixed. PS: Sorry to update a 2.5 years-old post...

Answer (score 1):

You are fairly limited by the vendor implementation of the [CSS paged media module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#first-pseudo), that said, you are able to use the module to target the first page by using the `:first` psuedo selector, e.g.:

```
@page:first {
    margin: 0
}
```

Should support / lack of implementation prove an issue- you will need to resort to adding your content into a series of elements which match the output page dimensions, then removing the margin/padding on the first.

Sadly, the control of printing from the web, even in this day and age, is not an easy process.

Comment: Thanks for your response. See the edit, I have added some code. This will not work since I want the margin on every page while still having the background at the top of the page.

Comment: `I do not want to have any margin on the print page` and `I am unable to do any margin on the second (or other pages)` suggests otherwise. The above will need to be added within your print media style. The above will not have a margin on only the first page. Im not too clear on what you're after.

Comment: Sorry for not being so clear. I want to have a margin on every page, but only for the text. There is a background image (see example), which needs to start at the very top of the page. Then I need some spacing until the text actually starts. Does this clarify a bit?